# Handling multiple events at the same time with JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to javaFx, and I want to create a griddles-like game.
First thing I want to do is to understand how the event handling works.

So, I created a simple board of rectangles and attached each rectangle with MouseEvent and an event handler iv'e created.

What I wanted to do is :
if the event is left mouse click, paint the rectangle in,
else if the event is MouseEnter and the left mouse is already pressed, paint the current rectangle in red.

I thought it should be pretty basic but when i implemented this I get only mouse pressed and entered on the first rectangle I click and mouse enter on the last rectangle when I dismiss the left mouse click..

this is the event handler class :

```
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    if(event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED)) {
        System.out.println("Pressed on " + row + ", " + col);
    } else if (event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED)) {
        System.out.println("Entered " + row + ", " + col);
    }
}
```

and this is where I attach the event :

```
    private void addRectangles() {
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(col * CELL_SIZE, row * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
            rectangle.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, new ShapeColorChanger(row, col, rectangle));
            getChildren().add(rectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

So, if i'm pressing a rectangle in 0,0 and dragging the mouse to rectangle 0,3 (while going over rectangles at 0,1 and 0,2) I get this output :

Entered 0, 0

Pressed on 0, 0

Entered 0, 3

Comment: What do you mean? I also tried to split into MouseEvent.Pressed and MouseEvent.Entered but got the same result

Comment: Go here this is what you need. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Listentoallmouseevents.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a drag gesture is detected, the mouse events are only delivered to the source of the gesture. No other nodes receive the mouse events.

If's possible to deal with this behavior by initiating a full drag and listening for the `MOUSE_DRAG_ENTERED` event:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 100);

    rect.setOnDragDetected(evt -> {
        // start full drag
        rect.startFullDrag();
    });
    rect2.setOnDragDetected(evt -> {
        // start full drag
        rect2.startFullDrag();
    });

    // print something when mouse enters the rects during a drag event.
    rect.setOnMouseDragEntered(evt -> System.out.println("enter"));
    rect2.setOnMouseDragEntered(evt -> System.out.println("enter"));

    Pane root = new Pane(rect, rect2);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: It works great!. But just to make sure, setting up event are done like this and not by attaching event handler via setEventHandler? which is better practice if there is one

Answer (score 1):

This is a controller version of http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Listentoallmouseevents.htm

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
{
     //Handles mouse events
     EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
         @Override
         public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
             System.out.println(mouseEvent.getEventType() + "\n"
                    + "X : Y - " + mouseEvent.getX() + " : " + mouseEvent.getY() + "\n"
                    + "SceneX : SceneY - " + mouseEvent.getSceneX() + " : " + mouseEvent.getSceneY() + "\n"
                    + "ScreenX : ScreenY - " + mouseEvent.getScreenX() + " : " + mouseEvent.getScreenY());
         }
     };

   //Creates 10 rectangles and set the Mouse events.
   List<Rectangle> rContainer = new ArrayList();
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
       rectangle.setX(50);
       rectangle.setY(50);
       rectangle.setWidth(200);
       rectangle.setHeight(100);
       rectangle.setOnMouseClicked(mouseHandler);
       rectangle.setOnMouseDragEntered(mouseHandler);
       rectangle.setOnMouseEntered(mouseHandler);
       rectangle.setFill(Color.BLUE);
       rContainer.add(rectangle);
   }

   //You code will be different here. Here you need to add the arraylist to your root. My root is an AnchorPane with id apMain in FXML
   apMain.getChildren().addAll(rContainer);
}
```